# 3D plots using maplot3d from matplotlib-

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to plot data which is in the following format :

`x = range(6)`
`y = range(11)`

and **z** depends on **x**, **y**

For each value of **x**, there should be a continuous curve that shows the variation of **z** w.r.t **y** and the curves for different values of **x** must be disconnected

I am using `mplot3d` and it is not very clear how to plot disconnected curves.

This is what it looks like using bar plots.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could overlay multiple plots using [Axes3D.plot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(6)
y = np.linspace(0, 11, 50)
z = x[:, np.newaxis] + y**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = '3d')
for xval, zrow in zip(x, z):
    ax.plot(xval*np.ones_like(y), y, zrow, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image]